# How can I display only Month/Year on a TcxDbDateEdit on Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm trying to display only the Month/Year date on my form via TcxDbDateEdit (Modifying the UI), is that possible?

Comment: Could set the displayformat property to a mask that excludes the day or use a TdxDBDateTimeWheelPicker and turn off the day wheel.

Comment: Thanks for your repply Brian, tried setting the displayformat property to 'mm/yyyy', but it did not work, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Month and year are not a *date*. Why would you expect a date edit control to work on non-date values?

Comment: I've seen some components that let you pick just '03/2021' instead of '10/03/2021', thought it was possible with a TcxDbDateEdit

Comment: Pick sounds like Edit - you asked about displaying (viewing).  Using an abbreviated date mask for display does work. For editing it does not since the underlying datatype needs a full date when you save/post.